# Check if user ID exists in Discord server in c#

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to make a auth link that the user will open then to get the client id from the user and check if the user is exists in a server. I'm not sure what lib should I use would love to get help thank you. I saw this code but this is in JavaScript and I need it in c# + the part of auth link

````
  USER_ID = '123123123';

if (guild.member(USER_ID)) {
  // there is a GuildMember with that ID
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

DSharpPlus is a fairly simple library to use. It'll throw 404 not found when the user isn't found so you'll need to check the ClientErrored event for failure.

```cs
var guild = //get current guild somehow
var user = await guild.GetMemberAsync(USERID);
```

Documentation on GetMemberAsync: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.Entities.DiscordGuild.html#DSharpPlus_Entities_DiscordGuild_GetMemberAsync_System_UInt64_

Repo: https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus

D#+ vs Discord.Net is DNet will give you more control over handling of events and messages. D#+ is more plug and play kind of deal.